# Avoid duplicate code in POJO Class

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd, code-duplication

Let's say we have 3 classes: A, B and C. Each class has the others in parameter. Like this: 
EDIT:

```
 +-----+  +-----+  +-----+
 |  A  |  |  B  |  |  C  |
 -------  -------  -------
 | X x |  | X x |  | Z z |
 | Z z |  | Y Y |  | Y y |
 -------  -------  -------
```

Getters and setters will be duplicated. So, is it a bad practice and should we avoid this ? Or does this should not be took as duplication code by code analyzers (eg. PMB) ?

I have thought about "strategy pattern", but I think it's maybe too much, just for getters and setters ...

EDIT : My first question is maybe not really clear. The question is if we have two classes (not linked) with a common attribut and exactly the same getter/setter. Sonar or PMD should consider these methods as duplicated code or not ? And if not, will it be fixed ?

Comment: These classes seem very tightly coupled. Why are they?

Comment: Code duplication is bad.  Why can't you just reference class B from A and use the methods that way?

Comment: A.getB() does not have to mean the same than C.getB(). So it is not duplicated. That said, I have seen somewhere `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations that help simplify even that (I do not recall which framework/library it was)

Comment: @Matt Ball you're right. I edited my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted, first consider whether you really need the duplication.  Maybe they should be in a common object that gets passed around.  Maybe they aren't needed.

Now lets assume they really are needed.  Which can be the case of course.  PMD's copy paste detector lets you set the minimum number of lines before it counts as a duplicate.  Since a getter/setter is only three lines each (or 6 for both), you could set the threshold just above there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a circular reference and is generally bad practice. Can you redesign to not do this?

Comment: Yes, you are right but in my real case there is no circular reference. I will edit my post to have a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating code is not always a wrong idea, in some cases it is unavoidable to make some clones. It is also true that setters and getters are nowadays being generated, but for and while loops are being generated too, and these codes should not automatically be excluded as they are being maintained manually. Aggressively eliminating code duplications without any consideration is not a good idea. Basically not all duplications are bad, and it does not always pays off their elimination. What pays off, is the so-called clone management, i.e. keeping track of the existing duplications and eliminating the ones that really cause troubles. For that you need a sophisticated tool, like FrontEndART's [QualityGate](http://www.quality-gate.com/) that incorporates a [CloneManager](https://www.quality-gate.com/modules/clonemanager/) module. It not only lists the duplications, but tracks their life through versions and lets you know what are the duplications that you should look at closer. You can check this tool out at the [online demo version of QualityGate](https://opensource.quality-gate.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Setters and getters are automatically generated code, so they are never code duplication (is someone, who writes them manually)?

The only problem you should consider, is if you have data duplication? And there's no way to say on your example, because field 'b' in classes 'A' and 'C' can have other meaning.

It's like field 'Address' in 'Client' and 'Building'. It means something else.

Comment: In Java, getters and setters are not automatically generated. You must be thinking of C#.

Comment: @Matt Ball: It is commong practise for java devs to let eclipse generate the getters and setters, eclipse also reflects field renames in the get/setters.